# Failed to calculate distances

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

We are running optaplanner in Greece with greece-latest.osm.pbf. In some cases when we add locations to the system, some coordinates are failing to calculate distances with the warning **Failed to calculate distances for ${location}, it will be discarded**. We noticed that this happens when we add locations which lead to a dead end street.

Do you have any idea of how we can solve this and actually don't discard these locations?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible cases I can think of:

- **No connection**: Consider an island which has no known ferries to it from the mainland.
  Now consider location A on that island and B on the mainland. What is the driving time from A to B?
- **No road nearby**: If no known road is nearby location A, for example in the middle of an island with no roads, or in the middle of the Alpes.

Both cases relate to the quality of the osm maps.